# Is it possible to check whether the location services are active?

Tags: windows-phone-7

is it possible to check whether the location services are active?

I mean Settings > Location > Location services

There is probably no direct API for calling, but could it work with the GeoCoordinateWatcher?

Answer (score 4):

```
            GeoCoordinateWatcher g = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            g.Start();
            if (g.Permission.Equals(GeoPositionPermission.Granted))
            {
                //Your location services is enabled. Go ahead.
                //Your codes goes here.
            }
            else if (g.Permission.Equals(GeoPositionPermission.Denied) || g.Permission.Equals(GeoPositionPermission.Unknown))
            {                    
                MessageBox.Show("Location services are disabled. To enable them, Goto Settings - Location - Enable Location Services.", "Location services", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
```

Comment: This kept returning Unknown for me, Chris R's answer provided the correct status.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to determine the status of the Location service:

```
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
if (GeoPositionStatus.Disabled == watcher.Status)
{
    // Watcher is disabled.
}
```

More realistically, you'll want to pay more attention to change to the status (just because the service isn't disabled doesn't mean you've got location data), so you shoudl take a look at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431782%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) for working with the Location service.

There's also a good post on [filtering and emulating location data using the Reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637517%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), which is perfect for that pre-device testing, though to save you time on that front the Widnows Phone Team have released the [Windows Phone GPS Emulator](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/01/28/windows-phone-gps-emulator.aspx).

Comment: You may need to actually call `Start()` on the watcher first and watch the status changes (which is why I gave you links for further reading). If you're running on the emulator, you will almost certainly get the `NoData` status all the time, which is another good reason for using the Windows Phone GPS Emulator, which wraps the location services.

Answer (score 3):

Even with the started `GeoCoordinateWatcher` you will get `NoData` if the sensor is disabled. What you should try using instead is TryStart:

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher g = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
MessageBox.Show(g.TryStart(false,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).ToString());
```

If it returns `False`, it means that the sensor is disabled. If it returns `True`, it is enabled. Set an appropriate timeout period (in the snippet above I am using 30 seconds) and delegate this process to a secondary thread, so it won't hang the UI.

Comment: Fun fact: In my app using TryStart with location disabled caused the application to crash, so yeah...

Answer (score 2):

You can add a StatusChanged event to your GeoCoordinateWatcher and test for GeoPositionPermission.Denied in the permissions when it fires.

```
watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
watcher.Start();

void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{

     if (watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Denied)
     {
         // Location services were disabled
     }
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Made this one based on [TeJ's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196588/tej) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13014400/1154733).

```
public override void OnNavigatedTo()
    {            
        using (var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher())
        {
            try
            {
                watcher.Start();
            }
            finally
            {
                IsAllowedInSystem = watcher.Permission.Equals(GeoPositionPermission.Granted);
                watcher.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

And my apps' `ToggleSwitch.IsEnabled` is binded to `IsAllowedInSystem`.
When i'm switching to *Location Service*, disable it and return back to app, my `ToggleSwitch` is disabled (also a string **"Please, enable Location Service in System settings"** in visible). When i'm switching to *Location Service*, enable it and return back to my app, my `ToggleSwitch` is enabled and user can set it up.